# Uphold the original numeration when using 'skip rows between index'

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, highlighting, tabularray

I have the same table (with n rows) several times and I want to highlight some rows.

But I need to skip some rows in each case (i.e. 'skip row 0,...,x'   or 'skip row x,...,n' etc.). 
 That means pgfplotstable is changing the numeration.

How can I uphold the original numeration, here in row 3 for example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
A    B     C
0   x     x
1    x     x
2    x     x
3    x     x
4    x     x
5    x     x
}{\mytable}

\begin{document}
\section{The row with Number 3 should be highlighted in both Tables}
\subsection{Good}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, 
every row no 3/.style={   before row=\rowcolor{yellow}},
skip rows between index={5}{6}
]{\mytable}

\subsection{Bad}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, 
every row no 3/.style={   before row=\rowcolor{yellow}},
skip rows between index={0}{2}
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems not hard to make [`pgfplotstable`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) work with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. And with `tabularray` it is easy to change the styles of the tables.

---

### New Solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
  A    B     C
  0    x     x
  1    x     x
  2    x     x
  3    x     x
  4    x     x
  5    x     x
}{\mytable}

\newcommand{\MyGobble}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\section{Highlight rows with number 3 with tabularray}

\subsection{Good}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  skip coltypes,
  begin table=\begin{tblr}{
    stretch = 0,
    rowsep = {3pt},
    columns = {c},
    row{5} = {yellow9},
    row{7} = {rowsep=0pt,cmd=\MyGobble},
  },
  end table=\end{tblr},
]{\mytable}

\subsection{Also Good}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  skip coltypes,
  begin table=\begin{tblr}{
    stretch = 0,
    rowsep = {3pt},
    columns = {c},
    row{5} = {yellow9},
    row{2-3} = {rowsep=0pt,cmd=\MyGobble},   
  },
  end table=\end{tblr},
]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Old Solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
  A    B     C
  0    x     x
  1    x     x
  2    x     x
  3    x     x
  4    x     x
  5    x     x
}{\mytable}

\newcommand{\MyGobble}[1]{}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytblra}
\SetTblrInner[mytblra]{
  stretch = 0,
  rowsep = {3pt},
  row{5} = {yellow9},
  row{7} = {rowsep=0pt,cmd=\MyGobble},
}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytblrb}
\SetTblrInner[mytblrb]{
  stretch = 0,
  rowsep = {3pt},
  row{5} = {yellow9},
  row{2-3} = {rowsep=0pt,cmd=\MyGobble},   
}

\begin{document}

\section{Highlight rows with number 3 with tabularray}

\subsection{Good}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  begin table=\begin{mytblra},
  end table=\end{mytblra},
]{\mytable}

\subsection{Also Good}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  string type,
  begin table=\begin{mytblrb},
  end table=\end{mytblrb},
]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```